# jQuery animation run one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a simple code like this:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />    
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="400px">
    <tr id="tr1">
        <td>
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            nima
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2">
        <td>
            2
        </td>
        <td>
            agha
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr3">
        <td>
            3
        </td>
        <td>
            ligha
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I write this code for change row one background

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Button1').on('click', function () {
            $('#tr1').stop()
                     .animate({ backgroundColor: "aqua" },800)
                     .stop()
                     .animate({backgroundColor: "white"},800);
        });
    });
```

but it run just one time and when I click again on `Button1` nothing changed. where is the problem?

(I use [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin)
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Button1').bind('click', function () {
       $('#tr1').animate({ backgroundColor: "aqua" },800)
             .animate({backgroundColor: "white"},800);
     });
});​
```

This works in google chrome... try it

Comment: If it does need a stop function, it only needs one before the first animate, and needs to be .stop(true,true)